# Hiding the 0 that shows when a user presses the AC button on my calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I've added an AC button to my JS calculator which resets the variables and displays 0 in the displayArea.

However when the user starts typing their first number the 0 stay's so it shows 03 instead of 3 etc - this doesn't impact the calculation.

I've tried to remove this using parseInt and an IF statement however it doesn't seem to work.

My best attempt so far is:

```
<p id="result-display">    </p>
let displayArea = document.getElementById('result-display');

else if (displayArea.innerHTML = 0) {
        buttonNumber = Number(e.target.innerText);
        displayValue = buttonNumber;
        displayArea.innerHTML = parseInt(displayArea.innerHTML += displayValue);
        }
```

If I change the 0 to a string e.g. '0' it works but then also stops the user entering multiple number values e.g. 56 would show as 5 etc.

My JSFiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/mh85skxv/3/

Comment: why not just clear the field using `displayArea.innerHTML = ""; ` ?

Comment: The equal sign (`=`) in JavaScript is for assignment, so when you write:

    else if (displayArea.innerHTML = 0) {

you are actually setting the `.innerHTML` to `0`, not checking for `0`.

To check if a value is equal to another, use `==`, for equality with conversion or use `===` to check for strict equality (equal without conversion).

Comment: Also, don't use `.innerHTML` when you aren't getting or setting any HTML content as `innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Instead use `.textContent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line at the end of your `calculate` function:

```
displayArea.innerHTML = Number(displayArea.innerHTML);
```

This will convert the content of the `displayArea` to a number, eliminating any leading zero.

If you don't want the 0 to appear when pressing AC just replace this line:

```
displayArea.innerHTML = 0;
```

with this:

```
displayArea.innerHTML = '';
```

Then parse your number like this in order to avoid NaN:

```
Number(displayArea.innerHTML) || 0;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, nice clean fix! Sounds like it was reading as a string hence by converting to a number using the Number function Javascript auto removes the 0?

UPDATE: This solution breaks the decimal point if added at the end of the calculate function, solved by putting within the else statement in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact solution, but here's a few tips from your question and your Fiddle code:

- `else if (displayArea.innerHTML = 0) {` can't work because you need `==` or `===`. Using only the equal sign doesn't check the value of `displayArea.innerHTML` but assigns it to `0`.
- Also `innerHTML` is not usually equal to `0`...maybe try `innerHTML.length` or something ?
- On your fiddle code I notice that you use statements like `return firstNumber = ...`. This is incorrect; instead, declare your variable `firstNumber` at the top, and for each switch case write something like:

  ```
      firstNumber = //whatever you want
      break; //this will ensure your code stops there
  ```

Hope this helps,